# Изучение php frameworks и jenkinks

Tags: yii2, laravel, symfony, jenkins, zend-framework

Посоветуйте книги по следующим темам:

1. zend framework
2. laravel framework
3. yii2 framework
4. symfony framework
5. jenkins

Если знаете, где скачать можно, то скиньте ссылочки пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думаю что есть много книг, посвященных фреймворкам или разработке на них.

Мой Вам совет - ознакомьтесь с документацией (не выучите наизусть, а именно ознакомьтесь), далее выбирайте интересующую Вас тему для учебного проекта(блог/доска объявлений/...) и пробуйте написать с использованием фреймворка.

Можно прочитать 10 книг о программировании, и так и не написать сортировку массива.

Я считаю, что лучше пробовать, чем просто читать.